# What happens when an exception is thrown in a Spark executor?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I have a spark structured streaming job where I am using `mapPartitions` , in which it is connecting to mongo client and enriching the stream data from kafka with data in mongo. Sometimes, mongo fails to connect, and I get an exception in one of the executor task. But the job does not stop, but it also stops consuming data from kafka. It goes into a hang state.

Currently, I am doing the usual,

```
try{

//enrich data

} catch {
  case e: Exception => {
     e.printStackTrace()
     sys.exit(0)
  }
} finally {
  //close mongo connection
}
```

If I throw an exception in an executor, does the driver capture exception? Also, is there a better way to handle such connection exceptions, such that the executor restarts, after reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Set the below configurations in Spark and Hadoop for retries respectively

> spark.task.maxFailures
>
> yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts

After the retries the exceptions will thrown back to the driver.

Also, the hang state maybe your mongo client waiting for timeout. Refer below for setting shorter timeout properties

https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient